# What is the algorithm for float placement?

Tags: floats, positioning

As discussed [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6419/asking-existing-questions-differently-to-improve-findability) on Meta, I wanted to know what the algorithm for placing floats is but did not find the corresponding [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) and [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/69445) as easily as I expected beforehand. Therefore, here I'm asking the same question in different words again and mark this new question as a duplicate, directly. That way, I hope to improve the findabilty of the great existing question and answer.

Comment: This question should be made a community wiki. Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to do this myself.

Comment: Flag it and request it.

Comment: @cfr Did that now.

Comment: I want to upvote this once it is CW-ified.

Comment: @CharlesStaats The response I got on the CW flag was that this is not really a CW post and that any reputation gained by it "would not hurt". I did what I could...